# Field writer interceptor

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'am studying Byte Buddy and I am trying to replace CGLib by it. I want to know if there is a way to implement to intercept writing to any field. I do not know the field type and I do not want to change the assigned value. I only want to log `field written!` on any access.

Example: if I have this class:

```
public class Ex {
    public int i;
    public String s;
    public boolean b;
}
```

later when I do this:

```
Ex e = new Ex();
e.i=1;
System.out.println("Value of i:" + i);
e.s="hello";
System.out.println("Value of s:" + hello);
```

it should output:

```
field written!
Value of i: 1
field writed!
Value of s: hello
```

In the help page under *Custom Instrumentation*, there is an example but it's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Is this something you were doing using cglib? Because [this is neither possible using Byte Buddy nor using cglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767111/can-cglib-be-used-to-intercept-direct-field).

The problem is that a field is not dispatched dynamically. Rather than redefining the class containing the field, you would need to redefine any class accessing the field what is close to impossible.

Comment: No. I could not implement that with CGLib. Today I have read ASM and now I understand that what I want is impossible. 
Tomorrow will try to rewrite my library with BB and see what happens.